# Question about cooking meat from a beginner

Tags: meat, boiling, fat, cook

This is the first time that I will cook meat. My question is that in the method of boiling/simmering meat, the foam of fats I see and I remove it with a large spoon. If I use another method for cooking meat (such as frying or grilling) will the fat remain in the meat?

Comment: If you want low fat meat cooking methods make little difference, you need to start with lower fat cuts.

Comment: Hi huab, we only take one question per post. You can use the small grey "Edit" link below your post to leave only one question, and we can then reopen. We can post the other one separately. By the way, we don't take question on "what is healthier", but if you want to know something measurable, like whether the fat content is reduced by your method, then we can take the question, preferably without references to health.

Comment: @rumtscho I click delete multipe times but nothing happen

Comment: @huab yes indeed, deletion is prevented when you have gotten good answers, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221. You don't need to delete though, the idea is that you edit it so only one question is left out of the two.

Comment: Side note: if you're just starting with cooking meat, boiling usually will not bring out the best flavour. At least brown it (fry / grill) first.

Comment: ah ok, that would probably be a stew... Even then, browning the meat first gives it a richer flavor. You can also drain some of the fat at this stage if that's your intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are skimming certainly is some fat, but it is probably mostly comprised of denatured proteins. We can't answer questions about healthy or not on this site.  That is all relative to you and your preferences. Salt enhances flavor.  Salting well in advance, removes moisture, concentrates flavor, and enhances flavor by penetrating the meat.

Comment: To add: the salt is then partially removed so the meat doesn't end up *too* salty

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza ....perhaps....it really depends on how much you use in the first place.  When I salt a chicken two days prior to roasting, for example, I don't rinse or remove any salt.

Comment: that's true. Absolutely no point in removing any salt, coarse or fine, 2 days after salting, a lot of migration already happened in that interval, completely different salting techniques